# Как НЕ удалять знаки табуляций и ему похожие

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется json ссылка из которой я вытягиваю параметр(raw) который содержит знаки табуляций и переноса строк

Типа таких: "\t" и "\r\n"

В интернете везде про то как их удалить, но мне нужно наоборот

В моем случаем после вытягивания они удаляются, автоматически, а мне нужно чтобы выводило также как указано по ссылке в файле json, то есть со всеми знаками

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    $calc = $('input[name=test]').val();
    $.getJSON( $calc ).done(function( data ) {
        $.each( data, function() {
            $draw = data.raw;
            $('.test').html($draw);
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: `\\t`----------

Comment: Не уверен, правильно ли я понял, но на всякий случай проверьте, не это ли вам нужно: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw

Comment: Тоже не до конца понял. Может, элемент `.test` сделать тегом `pre`?

Comment: Ответ @meine мне помог,
сделал так -

`data.raw.replace(/\t/g, '\\t').replace(/\r\n/g, '\\r\\n')`  
  

и получилось